# Retrieving all matplotlib axes in a Figure instance: should I use figure.get_axes() or figure.axes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, figure

Simple question: what is the difference between

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f = plt.figure()
a = f.get_axes()
```

and

```
f = plt.figure()
a = f.axes
```

for retrieving all axes in a Figure instance? Are there situations where either would be preferable?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [sourcecode for `get_axes`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/figure.py#L1265) is:

```
def get_axes(self):
    return self.axes
```

It therefore makes absolutely no difference at all which one you use.

Comment: Wow... that is strange. Thanks!